# WebView Download Image

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, webview

If I have a WebView, and I load a page with an image on it. If I right-click on it and click Download Image, the menu gets dismissed and from what I can see nothing happens.

Can someone inform me how this works? Is it saving it somewhere in particular I'm not looking at?

Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score 0):

It gets saved to your camera roll.

Comment: This is for Mac development not iOS. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a post about an app in OS X(not completely clear) then the image "should" save to the users downloads folder.

> /Users/UserName/Downloads

Comment: I meant for OS X, I click download image and it doesn't appear in the downloads folder, it's as if nothing happens

Comment: Interesting, I wish I could be more help on this, but the only places other than downloads that I can think of would be /Pictures /Documents, or maybe even in your iPhoto library or your app's app bundle itself. If it isn't in any of those places it may not even be saving.